# Tools for checking Spectre and Meltdown system vulnerabilities on Linux?

Tags: linux, security

I seek some reliable ways / tools for checking Spectre and Meltdown system vulnerabilities on Linux?

That are currently the following CVEs:

- CVE-2017-5753 [bounds check bypass] aka Spectre Variant 1
- CVE-2017-5715 [branch target injection] aka Spectre Variant 2
- CVE-2017-5754 [rogue data cache load] aka Meltdown aka Variant 3
- CVE-2018-3640 [rogue system register read] aka Variant 3a
- CVE-2018-3639 [speculative store bypass] aka Variant 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one good and maintained script on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker)).

Usage is as simple as running the script with superuser privileges, e.g.:

```
sudo ./spectre-meltdown-checker.sh
```

Possible result with proper patches in place:

[image: spectre & meltdown checker result]